# Unhappy komodo Edit

Tags: emoji, komodo

Look at the image, any ideas WTF happened with my Komodo?[image]

Comment: I could only guess with the information provided.  Update you post with Error logs (**Help > Troubleshooting > View Log File**), version of Komodo (**Help > About Komodo**), and OS type and version.

Now the part where I guess: Try changing the Icon set in your preferences: **Edit > Preferences > Appearance: Icon Set**

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  Issue was that the upgrade occurred as root.  Part of the ~/.komodoide/9.3/ items were owned by root.  chown user:group * -R fixed me right up.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but John is using Windows, not Linux @Dennis.  It does having something to do with the profile but it's your answer won't help.